# Why does fread() not work for files with html content?

Tags: html, c

I tried to read some files with the following code:

#### Main:

```
#define RESPONSE_MAX_LENGTH (1024 * 1024)       // Should be 1MB
char file_content[RESPONSE_MAX_LEGNTH];
memset(&file_content, 0, RESPONSE_MAX_LEGNTH);

request_get_file("/User/...", file_content);
```

#### Function Declaration:

```
int request_get_file(char* requested_file_path, char* buf) {
    int file_size = 0;
    FILE* fp = NULL;

    if ((fp = fopen(requested_file_path, "r+")) == NULL) {
        return errno;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    file_size = (int)ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    errno = 0;
    if (fread(buf, 1, file_size, fp) == 0) {
        if (!feof(fp)) {
            if (ferror(fp)) {
                printf("An error occured while reading the requested file. File size: %d\n", file_size);
                perror("fread()");
                return errno;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I am able to read .txt files, but when I open a html file, I get an error saying:

`fread(): Bad address` (Created with perror("fread")) 
`errno = 14`

For some reason, this error only occurs for some specific documents.

**Solution:**

I just realized that the problem seems to be related to a specific file. After renaming my test.html to test.txt and trying to open this one, the error is still there. Could that have to do with the file content? 
=> **Yes**, as the buffer I was writing the data was way too small.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the file name is `.html` and not `.htm`?

Comment: Absolutely. Would that make a difference? I updated my answer. Could that be because of the file content?

Comment: Please show the verbatim output of your program and show a [mcve]. Especially show what `buf` is and how it is allocated, the problem is most likely _there_

Comment: ^^^ what @MichaelWalz says.  Where's 'buf' declared, and how big is it?   I don't suppose, by any chance that your 'test.html' file is much bigger than the text files you were testing with?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that's embarrassing... buf was way too small, after giving it a larger size, it worked fine. Thanks! Should this question be deleted?

Comment: @T.Meyer no, it should not be deleted, but you need to show how `request_get_file` is called, because the problem is _there_. But the design of the program is wrong anyway, it should be up to `request_get_file` to allocate a buffer of sufficient size, because it is only _there_ where the file size is known. Your new program will fail again if you have a really big file.

Comment: Don't mark your questions "[SOLVED]" in the title. [Mark them solved by accepting an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-cant-i-mark-my-title-as-solved). Since there _is_ no answer posted here (yet you have added a solution to your question post) you can self-answer and accept your own answer, if you wish.

Comment: And would you be treating the file contents as a `nul`-terminated `char` string?  If so, be aware that `fread()` will not `nul`-terminate your "string".

Comment: @MichaelWalz So do you mean that I should declare and allocate the buffer *within* the function or declare it outside of it and allocate the memory inside (and return the address, f.ex.)?

Comment: @T.Meyer it's up to you, `request_get_file` should allocate the memory and for example return the buffer to the allocated memory: `char *request_get_file( ....`. And use like this: `char *myfile = request_get_file(...`, then once you're done with the content pointed my `myfile` free the memory  with `free(myfile);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the buffer I was writing to was way too small to hold all the data read by `fread()`.

My updated code:

#### Main:

```
char* buf = NULL;
request_get_file("/User/...", &buf);
```

#### Function Declaration:

```
int request_get_file(char* requested_file_path, char** buf) {
    int file_size = 0;
    FILE* fp = NULL;

    if ((fp = fopen(requested_file_path, "r+")) == NULL) {
        return errno;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    file_size = (int)ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    errno = 0;

    if ((*buf = calloc(file_size + 1, sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
        perror("calloc()");
        return errno;
    }

    if (fread(*buf, 1, file_size, fp) == 0) {
        if (!feof(fp)) {
            if (ferror(fp)) {
                printf("An error occured while reading the requested file. File size: %d\n", file_size);
                perror("fread()");
                return errno;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: @MichaelWalz Why is that? Could you improve my answer, please? Doesn't buf have a value due to calloc()?

Comment: Sorry, I missed something in your code, it looks correct to me. Forget by wrong comments. I've deleted them.